# openssl rand -base64 32 what is the equivalent in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to create a similar random base64 encoded string of 32 bytes, as

```
openssl rand -base64 32
```

in python

Can anyone help with, how this is done?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In python 3.6+:

```
from secrets import token_bytes
from base64 import b64encode

print(b64encode(token_bytes(32)).decode())
```

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html for token security details.

Comment: Brilliant, didn't know you could do that. Quite handy if you're not on a Linux system. Thanks

Comment: really appreciated for ur answer, I usually use `openssl rand -hex 20` and it worked similar to that, thanks!